# symfony2- Embedded Controller can't store value to database

Tags: symfony

I can't store value to database if use Embedded Controller, if I don't use embedded controller I can store it.

**Entity:**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tbl_mail")
 */
class Mail
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    public $email;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class SendContactController extends Controller
{
    public function Email(Request $request)
    {
        $mail = new Mail();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($mail)
            ->add('email','email')
            ->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($mail);
            $em->flush();
            //return $this->redirectToRoute('');
        }

        return $this->render('frontend/mail.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
}
```

**View (twig template)**:

```
<div>
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="OK" />
{{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
```

i render this controller in my base.html.twig
     {%render(controller('AppBundle\Controller\FrontEnd\SendContactController::Email  ')) %}

when I press **ok** to submit nothing happens.

Comment: <div>
   {{ form_start(form) }}
   {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="OK" />
   {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>




here is twig

Comment: What does the Symfony profiler tell you?  Have you tried debugging and showing form errors with `{{ form_errors(form) }}`?  What do you mean by 'embedded controller`?

Comment: I think if the controller name should be `EmailAction`. Can you add your url routes file attached to the controller function?

Comment: dont start function-names with an uppercase. Write emailAction(Request $request)

Comment: i render this controller with {% render(controller('AppBundle\\Controller\\FrontEnd\\SendContactController::Email')) %}

Comment: if i use route for twig template localhost://email , i can persist data to database , if i embedded this controller in my base.html.twig i can't persist

Comment: As Frankbeen said too name the function of the controller as `emailAction` and in your routes file change it too

Comment: i changed but it don't work

Comment: thanks all ! i give a patch to my controller and it worked `<div id>
    <form action="{{ path('sendmail') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
        {{ form_widget(form.email)}}
        <input type="submit" value="ok" />
    </form>
</div>` this my new twig for embedded